# Proving $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a.....}}}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a....}}}}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I checked many values of this inequality, but I don't have the complete proving.

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a.....}}}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a....}}}}=1$$ if $$a>1$$

Comment: How do you define the infinitely nested radicals? Probably $x_0 = y_0 = a$, and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{a+x_n},\, y_{n+1} = \sqrt{a-y_n}$?

Comment: Inequality?​​​​​

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Define $x = \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a +\cdots}}}$ and $y = \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a -\cdots}}}.$ Then we have $x^2 = a+ x$ and $y^2 = a-y$.

Now compute $(x+y)(x-y) = x^2 - y^2 = x+y$. Cancelling $x+y$ from both sides gives $x-y = 1$, which is the result you're after.

(Of course, I've ignored convergence issues here and just worked formally).

Comment: What about the condition, is it necessary or not

Comment: Very nice, but I would write $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2=(a+x)-(a-y)=x+y\implies(x+y)(x-y)=x+y\implies{x-y}=1$ just to make it a little clearer.

Comment: For $a < 1$, my guess is that you get convergence problems in the second nested radical - after all, if you define $y_0 = \sqrt{a},$ $y_n = \sqrt{a+y_{n-1}}$, then you immediately get that $y_1$ is imaginary and $y_2$ is complex. I should stress that I've not thought rigorously about the convergence here, but given the way you've phrased the question - presuming it comes from some kind of reputable source - it seems believable that the condition defines some sort of region of convergence.

Comment: (Of course I meant $y_n = \sqrt{a - y_{n-1}}$, not a $+$!). To back up my hunch, a simple check for $a = 1$ shows that the sequence is $y_0 = 1$, $y_1 = 0,$ $y_2 = 1$, ... which obviously doesn't converge!

Answer (score 2):

this is 
$$
\lim U_n - \lim u_n
$$
where
$$
U_{n+1 } = \sqrt{a + U_n}
\\
u_{n+1 } = \sqrt{a - u_n}
$$

Provided that both limits exists, there are solutions of
$$
U^2 = a + U\\
u^2 = a - u
$$
the part $b^2 - 4ac $ is the same, so it remains only the $-\frac b {2a}$ part of both quadratic equations, giving
$$
U - u = \frac 12 - \left(-\frac 12\right) = 1
$$

---

Another 'proof':

\begin{align} \delta &=
 \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a +\cdots}}}- \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a -\cdots}}}
\\&= 
\frac{a + \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a +\cdots}} - \left[a - \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a -\cdots}}\right]}
{\sqrt{a + \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a +\cdots}}}+ \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a -\cdots}}}}
\\&= 
\frac{ \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a +\cdots}} + \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a -\cdots}}}
{\sqrt{a + \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a +\cdots}}}+ \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a - \sqrt{a -\cdots}}}}
\\&=1
\end{align}

Comment: What about the condition, is it necessary or not